# Implement QR Codes or NFC Tags for CRUD Actions

Tags: api, nfc, qr-code

I have a web app developed for inventory in my company. And my idea now is to implement either QR codes or NFC tags on the boxes in the warehouse so employees can scan them and then a popup comes up on top of your smartphone with a text and a + and - button and you can say -3 and press apply to make a request to the API. Is this possible in any way? And if so, with which technology? I've never worked with anything like this and am unfortunately completely at a loss.